# How to add paragraph between mergefields in word mailmerge

Tags: mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I want to be able to add an automatic paragraph between mergefields in mailmerge. The words of the merge fields are written together with no space between them. how do I format it in this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two consecutive mergefields looking like `<<field1>> <<field2>>` couldn't you just do something like:-

`document.merge(field1='your field1 text here\n', field2='your field2 text here')`

The \n will insert the newline at the end of field1.